# How to make a blinking printf command (using tput) stop manually after a while in bash (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: bash, printf, ubuntu-18.04, tput

I know that I can use the below command to blink a prinf or an echo command but how to stop it after a while or after a process is complete? I am writing a script and the blinking would indicate a process is being executed, once it stopped the user knows that step is completed.

```
BLINK=$(tput blink)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
printf "${BLINK}${GREEN} ------- installing something -------  \n\n${NORMAL}"
```

Comment: designate the print line (`tput sc`), print the blinking text, run the installation (in the background?) and once the installation is complete ... go back to print line (`tput rc`), print the non-blinking text; if the 'installation' generated any output you'll likely want to move the cursor back down to the line after the 'installation' output

Answer (score 2):

I use...

```
printf "Normal \e[5m\e[31mBlink\e[0m\n"
```

...and got it from: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

So i think you need the `\e[0m` to end up with normal output.